# In switch statements, why do all statements get executed after a true statement if break is not given?

Tags: c, switch-statement

In a `switch`/`case` statement, the `case` statements is for checking the condition, so why should it execute the statements which are false? Even if it continues execution of all the cases up to the end of the program if `break` is not given, won't the `case` statement check the condition. Isn't its internal working same as `if`/`else` statements? If not, then how does it work internally?
Language: C

Comment: break in the switch statement is used to terminate the execution sequence  (just like another sequence in programming flow),  and then control goes to the next statement in the program. If you omit the break then the flow of control will follow every case in the flow.

Comment: Not all languages work like this. Please tag your questions with a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a case label (which isn't a statement) doesn't check any condition. In fact it doesn't do anything at all (notice how you can have multiple cases in a row?) and doesn't produce any code. Upon entering the switch, execution jumps to the matching case. And that's it. Once you're in the block, the labels don't do anything, but a `break` will get you out.